# hi I am new to stack overflow and programming. I was solving an EASY problem of mysql on leetcode and ran into an error

Tags: mysql

got this error message  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO 'employees1'"

## Write your MySQL query statement below

```
create table employees1 (emp_id INT(6) UNSIGNED, event_day DATE NOT NULL, in_time int NOT NULL,
out_time int NOT NULL )    
INSERT INTO 'employees1' ('emp_id', 'event_day', 'in_time', 'out_time')
values (1,20201128,4,32),
(1,20201128,55,200)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use a semicolon at the end of a statement, and use backticks for table names and column names. Those are fundamental rules which can be easily learned should you decide to spend a little more efforts.

```
create table employees1 (emp_id INT(6) UNSIGNED, event_day DATE NOT NULL, in_time int NOT NULL,
out_time int NOT NULL );    
INSERT INTO `employees1` (`emp_id`, `event_day`, `in_time`, `out_time`)
values (1,20201128,4,32),
(1,20201128,55,200);
```